# Switching dynamicaly database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to create a multilanguage application based on ASP.NET MVC 4.
Unfortunately,a one database suits a one language. The structure and terminology are the same as opposed to the content which is changing.
Is there any possibility for the application to change a database according to choice of the language?

Comment: How do you access the database, L2S, EF, any other ORM, a simple data reader? I would say, just use the connection string which corresponds to the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add different connection strings to your *web.config* - one for each supported language:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
  <add name="northwind-en" connectionString="server=(local);database=NorthwindEnglish;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
  <add name="northwind-fr" connectionString="server=(local);database=NorthwindFrench;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then select connection string depending on required language, or default one if there is no specific database for selected language:

```
var availableLocales = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                                .Cast<ConnectionStringSettings>()
                                .Select(cs => cs.Name)
                                .Select(n => n.Substring(n.IndexOf('-') + 1));
```

Comment: This is good start. Do you have any idea how can I use this variable with DbContext(EF)? In app there are several places where I use for example:

`using(ProductEntity product = new ProductEntity()) { ... }`

Comment: @mkozak there is overload of `DbContext` class constructor, which accepts connection string. You can pass connection string when creating `ProductEnity` context (pass string to base class constructor)