# ASP Web API share code base among different app instances?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web-config

This question has been asked a few times, but I haven't found an answer specific to my problem.

Essentially I have one ASP Web API app which can be deployed any number of times (currently 50) which will connect to a different database. Everything is literally identical except for the DB connection string in web.config and the virtual directory it sits under.

Right now, we're using web deploy to manually update all sub directories with code updates. We've automated it, but it's still painful, especially when there are errors.

Just wondering if there is a way to have the main codebase somewhere (let's say the root of the site), with virtual directories under it with just the web.config? I don't think this is possible based on other threads I have found (although they're much older).

I've tried to set it up like this, having virtual directories under the parent site (which physically point to the parent site) and having a different web.config in the physical sub directory, but it does nothing.

Alternatively, is a better way to dynamically generate the DB connection string in code? I don't really like this solution, but is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any other reason why you have 50 instances. If it's just a different db connection, you should have one "multi-tenant" instance and based on request you decide to which db you will connect..

Comment: Nope no reason, not sure why this approach was chosen but I've ended up with it. Does this mean the connection string will be generated dynamically in code?

Answer (score 2):

I would go for multi-tenant support in API here as well. Alot of advantages with one entry point for the API calls - statistics, throttling, logging etc.

Make a HTTP security module to choose database depending on api key supplied. Just important this mapping is secure and well tested.

I would also consider combining into one database and restrict on schema or something, but that's maybe out of scope here...

Comment: Yeah, separate databases is a business requirement unfortunately. Is multi-tenant support an ASP specific thing or is it just generic? If it's generic, I assume you mean just have something parse in the header (perhaps the virtual directory name as that will be simple) and map it to a database in code?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to generate connection string. I would say instead of having 50 instances you can have 1 instance and 50 different configurations/connection strings, and based on your current request context you can pick corresponding connection string. You can have some kind of convention for naming connection strings or something similar, it's up to you, and then I would create a connection factory class, and put there all connection creation logic.

The link below is a good starting point, it's really similar example.

[Switching dynamicaly database in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616395/switching-dynamicaly-database-in-asp-net)

Comment: Ah right, understood. One thing I probably didn't make clear though is that new instances can be created at any time by anyone (providing they supply payment information). So I don't want to manually add connection strings to web.config, as this will cause an app pool recycle wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, when you save webconfig, app pool will recycle, but if you have session state persisted outside of IIS you are pretty much safe. Here is how you can configure sql server to keep your session state https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753897(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Hmmm so I have it working, but not sure this is the best way to solve it. Essentially, for each API call I have: DataModel db = new DataModel(Request.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot.Substring(1)). This grabs the virtual directory which the current request is coming from. In my DataModel initializer class, I then have a method which maps the virtual directory to a DB name and then dynamically changes the connection string using the new DB name. This shouldn't take too much of a performance hit, as the database gets initialized with every API call anyway I think?

Comment: The only thing you should care about in that case is the getting correct connection string and how long that takes. Regarding implementation it's hard to say without code but anyway that's not the topic of this discussion